# apostrophe-rich-text anchor name and adding attributes to elements in CKEditor programmatically

Tags: apostrophe-cms

My Problem is that and anchor in apostrophe-rich-text produces a not working markup in html.

I have the following setup for my apostrophe-rich-text:

```js
'apostrophe-rich-text': {
    toolbar: [
        'Styles',
        'Bold',
        'Italic',
        'Blockquote',
        'BulletedList',
        'Link',
        'Anchor',
        'Table'
  ],
    styles: [
        { name: 'Default', element: 'p' }
  ]
}
```

I'm using more styles in general but didn't wanted to list them all here. Everything works like expected except `Anchor`.

Anchor produces this this in html.

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a name="section-one">incididunt</a> qui officia deserunt</p>
```

Which obviously can not work. Did I made something wrong or is this a bug?

There is also the possibility to select "Link" and choose "Anchor" in the dropdown menu for "Link Type", unfortunately my anchors are not recognized, I only get the message "(No anchors present in the document)".

I use a dropdwon menu for on page navigation the anchors are definitely there. You can see it [here](https://material-cms.com).

Additionally i want to add a class to all a elements and for performance and safety reasons `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to all external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify the CKEDITOR instance with a really good solution.
With this you can programmatically add just about anything to any element.

As described in the [Global CKeditor configuration](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/ckeditor.html#global-ckeditor-configuration) section I have added the following:

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/public/js/user.js

apos.define('apostrophe-areas', {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    // Use the super pattern - don't forget to call the original method
    var superEnableCkeditor = self.enableCkeditor;
    self.enableCkeditor = function() {
      superEnableCkeditor();
      // Now do as we please
      CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
        var editor = ev.editor;
        editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
          elements : {
            // Add attributes to a
            a : function( element ) {
              // Add accent-color class to all links
              if ( !element.attributes.class ){
                element.attributes.class = 'accent-color';
              }
              // Add _blank and noopener and noreferrer to external links
              if ( !element.attributes.rel ){
                // Get content's a href values
                var url = element.attributes.href;
                // Extract host names from URLs (IE safe)
                var parser = document.createElement('a');
                parser.href = url;
                // Set additional attributes
                var hostname = parser.hostname;
                if ( hostname !== window.location.host) {
                    element.attributes.rel = 'noopener noreferrer';
                    element.attributes.target = '_blank';
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
      })
    };
  }
});
```

For the `rel` attributes of course i had to allow it with the `allowedAttributes` method:

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js

// Changing the allowed HTML tags in rich text widgets
module.exports = {
  sanitizeHtml: {
    allowedTags: [
      'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'p', 'a', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'strong', 'em', 'blockquote', 'iframe'
    ],
    allowedAttributes: {
      '*': ['style', 'class'],
      a: [ 'style', 'name', 'href', 'target', 'rel', 'class' ]
    },
    allowedSchemes: ['http', 'https', 'ftp', 'mailto', 'tel']
  }
};
```

That adds a lot of flexibility to the CKEditor used in Apostrophe and can be very useful for various situations where attributes should be programmatically added to elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why would that not work? Using the `name` attribute isn't the current recommended practice, but it should still work. The editor likely uses that because it's an older version of CKEditor.

For `anchor-jump` you could add a text style for it like any other text style. Updating the anchor tool button might be possible, but it would involve customizing CKEditor plugin code.

In my experience the link tool can find anchors pretty well. It could be specific to using the `name` attribute rather than an `id`, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I understood now `name` is the anchor which should be jumped to but i thought about the actual trigger which should be clicked. This must always have a `href`. My site anchors were not found cause I'm editing a piece so I'm theoretically not on the same page but I found a good workaround, using `link` and protocol `other` then i can add a links with `#` freely.  `scroll-behavior: smooth;` helped for the scrolling. I will research further on how to improve CKEditor I have understood now that's not mainly a apostrophe thing. Thx for the info helped anyway.

Comment: I have now found a much better method than styles for attributes to be added to all elements or under certain conditions. This way the user does not have to select a style which is often forgotten. I think it makes sense to add this to the apostrophe documentation. I can do this if you are wish.

Comment: Please create an issue in the core repo with details. Thank you.